# Linking DStar repeaters using Icom syntax

Tags: repeater, icom, d-star

I would like to monitor a remote repeater (VE2RM) through my local repeater (VE3TTT).  I am trying to figure out how to link them - specifically using the Icom ID-52A commands/syntax.  I found some *old* posts which explain how to manually enter L and U commands in UR and RPT2, but I think there is a *new* way using Icom menu commands.

I tried setting VE3TTT B as my FROM repeater, and VE2RM B as my TO repeater.  But there is no "link" or "Unlink" possible. which makes me think I'm doing this wrong.

I tried setting VE3TTT B as my FROM repeater, and VE3TTT G as my TO repeater.  But there is no way to specify VE2RM B as the UR.

Can someone explain how to do this using Icom menus?

UPDATE: I called Icom support and was told this is not possible using the menus (in DR mode).  I had to create three memorized channels to Link/Unlink/Use the repeater-to-repeater link.  That seems crazy...even in DR mode I can't do it?  I'm hoping he was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to:

1. Enter DR mode
2. Select your local repeater (and module) `VE3TTT B` as the FROM repeater
3. In the TO repeater, select `Gateway CQ`
4. Now you need to select the remote gateway by scrolling to the appropriate group, then city repeater to find `VE2RM  B`
5. Now you should have your local repeater in FROM and the remote in TO...
6. You now need to key your mic to actually setup the route on your local repeater.

And before doing all this, you should give a courtesy announcement on the repeater to the effect of, "Yo, my peeps! gonna hook up to another 'peter so strap in!!" Perhaps translating that to the local vernacular.

I've had success doing this with various repeaters, hope you do too!